# No diferenciar nombres de atributos CFDI en XML

Tags: c#, vb.net, xml

estoy realizando una aplicación que se encarga de separar archivos XML en base a unos parámetros, hasta ahí bien, pero ahora con los cambios del CFDI tronó mi programación, ya que los usuarios pueden tener mezclados los documentos del cfdi 3.2 y 3.3 en una misma carpeta.

Lo que me truena el recorrido de los documentos es que en versión 3.2 obtenía el dato de esta manera:

```
strVersion = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Comprobante")(0).Attributes("version").Value
```

pero ahora con el cambio al 3.3 me falla ya que cambiaron a mayúscula la primera letra de los atributos, y ahora seria

```
strVersion = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Comprobante")(0).Attributes("Version").Value
```

habrá una forma de que en caso de que el atributo `("version")` no exista entonces tome el valor  `("Version")`, o que en `Attributes` no distinga entre `version` y `Version`, espero darme a entender y puedan sugerirme algo.

Anexo la estructura de los XML para ver si se puede recuperar sus valores de otra forma diferente a lo que yo hago.

> Versión 3.3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante Certificado="MIQ=" Fecha="2018-02-01T01:56:11" Folio="012180001054132653" FormaPago="03" LugarExpedicion="06600"  TipoCambio="1" TipoDeComprobante="I" Total="0000.00" Version="3.3" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd">
    <cfdi:Emisor Nombre="BBVA BANCOMER, S A" RegimenFiscal="w232" Rfc="RFSGEGHSFS"/>
    <cfdi:Receptor Nombre="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" Rfc="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" UsoCFDI="XXX"/>  
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

> Versión 3.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/ine http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/ine/ine11.xsd" version="3.2" serie="TF" sello="J="  noCertificado="00001000000402403936" certificado="MI=" condicionesDePago="PAGO INMEDIATO SIN DESC. POR P" subTotal="0.00" TipoCambio="1.00000" Moneda="MXN" total="0.00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
    <cfdi:Emisor rfc="RFCGF242FD" nombre="Lorem">       
    </cfdi:Emisor>
    <cfdi:Receptor rfc="EWCVFFSFDF" nombre="Lorem imp">     
    </cfdi:Receptor>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para XML en .NET te recomiendo que uses la clase XDocument y sus relacionadas.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("32.xml");
//XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("33.xml");
XAttribute xAttVersion = null;
xAttVersion = xDoc.Root.Attribute("version");
if(xAttVersion == null) xAttVersion = xDoc.Root.Attribute("Version");
string version = xAttVersion.Value;
Console.WriteLine(version);
```

UPDATE:

Hola para obtener nodos es con XElement, siguiendo el ejemplo anterior sería:

```
XNamespace ns_cfdi_3 = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3";
XElement xReceptor = xDoc.Root.Element(ns_cfdi_3 + "Receptor");
string rfcReceptor = xReceptor.Attribute("Rfc").Value;
```

Es decir Root es la raíz ó primer nodo, de ahí con XElement accesas a los siguientes nodos usando el namespace al que pertenece. Los atributos del nodo para este caso de CFDI no requieren namespace sólo indicas el nombre.

Comment: Muchas gracias @shop350, aplicando este método como podría recuperar el **RFC del receptor**, no podría usar root.Attribute o si?

Comment: Si alguien tiene la misma pregunta, se puede encontrar más información en este [enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35370262-cd6c-4ec4-92c4-27c6b4db9e82/extracting-xml-attribute-and-element-name-values-and-data-values-from-nodes?forum=xmlandnetfx)

Comment: Hola te he puesto el ejemplo, sólo debes ir nodo por nodo y puedes accesar a cualquier dato, saludos.

Comment: Excelente, he seguido estas sugerencias y me va perfecto.